# I can't see the error in my code. The code is running but it is stuck in a loop

Tags: java, loops, math

I was writing code that finds the sum of the digits of the product of all n-digit numbers.
I can't see the error in my code. The code is running but it is stuck in a loop.
This is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SummarynDigitNumbersDigitMultiplyDigit {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n = s.nextInt();
        double Digit;
        double Summary = 0;
        double MultipliedDigit = 1;
        double start = Math.pow(10,n-1), finish=Math.pow(10,n);
        for ( double i = start; i<finish; i++){
            while (i>0) {
                Digit = i % 10;
                MultipliedDigit *= Digit;
                i = i / 10;
            }
            Summary+=MultipliedDigit;
        }
        System.out.println(Summary );
    }
}
```

If I write 1 to n Summary = 45 .

Comment: Your inner `while` loop will run until `i` is `0` or smaller, meaning after it is done running it will pretty much make sure that the outer loop condition of `i<finish` never becomes false.

Comment: `i` will eventually jump between `0` and `1`, because you're using that variable as a condition for your `for` loop where it gets incremented but you're using it for calculations later down the line where you decrease it again.

Comment: for example i =10 Digit1 = 0 then i = 1 then Digit2 = 1 i = 0. because i=i/10 take whole part for example 0=1/10

Comment: Then while loop exit to for loop and i take 11 . But my for loop is stucking.

Comment: @SolijonIminov no, `i` will not be `11`, it will be `1` because you've changed `i` in your `while` loop to be  `i = i / 10;`. So after that loop `i` has become `0` and then your `for` loop increments it to `1` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inner (`while`) loop, you set `i = i/10`, effectively making sure that `i` will never reach the termination condition of the `for` loop